# Python - Selenium won't go back to previous page

Tags: python, selenium, web

When accessing the website in variable "url" it automatically accepts cookies, writes the dates and then clicks search, but once it does, 98 applications are shown making it click the first application. I made it so it goes back, redoes it so then it SHOULD click the second application, instead it returns an error.

Can someone try and help make my script go back to the last page and click the second application?

Error:

```
[8796:7240:0913/132540.843:ERROR:install_util.cc(603)] Failed to read HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\MachineLevelUserCloudPolicyEnrollmentToken: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51391/devtools/browser/0f49248f-88a3-48b4-bf7c-975f7b52185a
Worked???
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\DBaldwin\Desktop\sel.py", line 34, in <module>
    e.click()
  File "C:\Users\DBaldwin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\DBaldwin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\DBaldwin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\DBaldwin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Code:

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "http://www.fareham.gov.uk/casetrackerplanning/applicationsearch.aspx"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\DBaldwin\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_id("lnkAllowCookies").click()

def rerun():
    driver.find_element_by_id("BodyPlaceHolder_uxLinkButtonShowAdvancedSearch").click()

    time.sleep(3)

    driver.find_element_by_id("uxStartDateDecisionTextBox").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("uxStartDateDecisionTextBox").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("uxStartDateDecisionTextBox").send_keys("1/8/2018")

    driver.find_element_by_id("uxStopDateDecisionTextBox").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("uxStopDateDecisionTextBox").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_id("uxStopDateDecisionTextBox").send_keys("308/2018")

    driver.find_element_by_id("BodyPlaceHolder_uxButtonSearch").click()

    time.sleep(3)

rerun()

elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("searchResultsCell")

for e in elements:
    e.click()
    driver.back()
    rerun()
    print("Worked???")
```

Answer (score 5):

`elements` list defined on the main page becomes stale after you leave that page. You can try to replace

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("searchResultsCell")

for e in elements:
    e.click()
```

with

```
elements_len = len(driver.find_elements_by_class_name("searchResultsCell"))

for index in range(elements_len):
    driver.find_elements_by_class_name("searchResultsCell")[index].click()
```

Also if elements with class name `"searchResultsCell"` are links, you can do:

```
links = [link.get_attribute("href") for link in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("searchResultsCell")]
for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
```

Comment: File "sel.py", line 31, in <module>
    driver.get(link)
  File "C:\Users\Goten\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 332, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "C:\Users\Goten\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 320, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Goten\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response

Comment: How does those URLs looks like? Does first approach work?

Comment: I fixed the issue, now once it loops round twice it won't click the new page

Comment: Try to implement [ExplicitWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

Comment: do you mean something like make it sleep for some seconds?

Comment: Not to sleep, but to wait for required element to be clickable or for visibility of elements with class name `searchResultsCell`...

Comment: @FeitanPortor , as I found out element with class name `searchResultsCell` is not a link, but parent `div` of link, so you just need to replace `driver.find_elements_by_class_name("searchResultsCell")` with `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".searchResultsCell a")` to make second approach work

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the error trace, you will see a StaleElementReferenceException.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

This error raises because of the web element that you are performing the operation on is no longer attached to the currently loaded DOM. Since you have get the elements at the intial page load and With you navigating back and forth through the web application, those stored web elements are not referring to the currently loaded DOM. Those elements are form the initial page load.

As per my thoughts, the best approach you could follow is to fetch the web element each time so the web elements are attached to the current DOM.